# How to add a network printer on mac that requires authentication

Tags: macos, printing

In our office, we have a printer accessible through our network. I was able to find and add the printer to my mac, which is El Captain, but it is not working since it requires authentication. When adding the printer, there is nowhere I can insert my credentials.
[image: Adding the printer]
Also, when added, there is nowhere I can authenticate! Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

1. Right-click on the toolbar in the gap between Windows and the Search bar, then choose Customise Toolbar….
2. Add the Advanced button to the toolbar and Done.
3. Choose the Advanced tab you just added.
4. Choose Type: Windows printer via spoolss.
5. For URL, enter `smb://` followed by the address you were already entering.
6. You will need to manually set the driver. Choose a Driver… → Select Software….

Comment: This _kind of_ worked; I was able to add the printer. But, there is another authentication step that I don't know how to include. In the other Windows machine, under the security tab, I should enter a 4-digit code; however, there was no part here (on Mac) that I was asked for this code. So, I am getting `authentication failed` all the time.

Comment: @Matin Can you add a Windows screenshot to your question showing where this PIN is meant to go?

Comment: It's actually available under `printing preferences`. Once I select the printer, I can go to printing preferences and under `Valid Access` I can add the 4-digit code. Please see this screenshot. [https://imgur.com/a/op4YL](https://imgur.com/a/op4YL)